# AnimatedContentTransitionScope is unresolved when i run the compileReleaseKotlin gradle task

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, native-android

Im building an android application using Jetpack Compose `1.5.0-alpha02` and utilizing the animated content composable as below

```
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContent
import androidx.compose.runtime.*

//...

var progress by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }

AnimatedContent(
    targetState = progress,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    transitionSpec = {
        slideInOutLeft()
    }
) {
// my other composables
}
```

I extracted the `slideInOut()` function to a file called transitions so that i can reuse it in multiple places but this is its implementations

```
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentTransitionScope
import androidx.compose.animation.ContentTransform
import androidx.compose.animation.core.EaseInOut
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.animation.with


inline fun <reified T> AnimatedContentTransitionScope<T>.slideInOutLeft(): ContentTransform
    = slideIntoContainer(
        animationSpec = tween(300, easing = EaseInOut),
        towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left
    ).with(
        slideOutOfContainer(
            animationSpec = tween(300, easing = EaseInOut),
            towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left

        )
    )
```

When i run and build the app on an emulator or physical device i get no errors but when i try to push it to github, the `gradle compileReleaseKotlin` gradle task was failing. and this is the error I'm getting

```
Unresolved reference: AnimatedContentTransitionScope
```

Ive tried upgrading dependencies, downgrading them reading the documentation searching the internet using gpt4 but no results. Please any help will be highly appreciated as i dont know whats wrong

Answer (score 1):

update accompanist navigation animation dependencies to 0.31.5-beta

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.31.5-beta"
```